# Parsing JSON in Power BI with a Custom Structure

Tags: json, powerbi

I am attempting to parse JSON data in Power BI that has a structure like the following:

```
{"name":{"0":"Jerry","1":"Ron","2":"Sally","3":"Sue"},"grade":{"0":78,"1":99,"2":88,"3":97}}
```

Currently, I have tried transforming the data via transform -> To Table -> Parsed JSON but it returns the table in the following format which when I attempt to expand rows shows the table two below. If I expand again, the data is not in the correct format (see table 3, through all the elements in my data). I need the data to be in the format like seen in table 4. Is there a different way to parse data that is in this custom structure?

```
Table 1:
 | Column1 | 
| -------- | 
| *Record*   | 

Table 2:
| Name | Score |
| -------- | -------------- |
| *Record* | *Record* |
```

Table 3:

| Name.0 | Name.1 | Name.2 | Name.3 | Grade.0 | Grade.1 | Grade.2 | Grade.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jerry | Ron | Sally | Sue | 78 | 99 | 88 | 87 |

Table 4:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Jerry | 78 |
| Ron | 99 |
| Sally | 88 |
| Sue | 87 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let
    Source = Json.Document("{""name"":{""0"":""Jerry"",""1"":""Ron"",""2"":""Sally"",""3"":""Sue""},""grade"":{""0"":78,""1"":99,""2"":88,""3"":97}}"),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"0", "1", "2", "3"}, {"0", "1", "2", "3"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Expanded Value"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"name", type text}, {"grade", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Results in
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Would there be a way to dynamically expand the values in the `#"Expanded Value"` step so that if there were more entries created it would automatically expand all records and not cut it off after the 4th?

Comment: I am able to just expand the fields manually and then follow the subsequent steps, but would like for it to be able to happen dynamically as I load additional data into the data model.

Comment: @deeth128 If all the Records have the same structure (same name'd fields), you can replace the column names in the `Expanded Value` steps with `Record.FieldNames(#"Converted to Table"[Value]{0})`. If they will not have the same structure, then you'll have to extract them from all of the records, and create a distinct list to use in that step.